# Parsing Javascript variable to AS3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to write a simple 2 way chat but got a problem. I'm sure it's very basic but couldn't figure out since I'm new to this.

Below is my JS code to pass a streamID to AS3:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'action=sd_chat_code&chat_code='+chat_code,
    success: function(data){
        object.streamCompanion(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and in AS file, I got the `streamID` passed through as below:

```
public function streamCompanion(data):void {
    var netStreamObj:NetStream = new NetStream(_nc);
    netStreamObj.play(data);
    _client.attachNetStream(netStreamObj);
}
```

Here's my code so you can check https://codepen.io/adamboy_1802/pen/MpqyML

The variable `data` above returns "12345" correctly. I tried to output is via JS and there's nothing wrong:

```
ExternalInterface.call("function() { console.log("+data+") }")
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**(Solved)**

So after trying to create a text box and output the variable `data` in Flash instead of alert it out via jQuery, the problem relied in my ajax call, where I use `echo json_encode(my_var)`, simply change it to `echo my_var` fixed the problem.

Comment: what is `ExternalInterface` ? Flash API has `ExternalInterface` class but there it has not property `class` as far as I can see. And I'm not very familiar with jQuery but shouldn't your data be `'action=sd_chat_code&chat_code=12345`  instead of simply `12345`?

Comment: _"if I manually type in netStreamObj.play('12345'), it's working correctly"_ how is it working? What (result) happens exactly?  I'm sure `data: 'action=sd_chat_code&chat_code='+chat_code` is simply sending a string, but according to [**the manual**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play()) a URL (string) for a media file is the expected. Look into JS and AS3 sockets for chat app. If just passing text between an embedded Flash vs JS then use external interface to pass Strings to functions. I'm not sure what you want to do..

Comment: Well, I never actually tired to stream any videoor even use `ExternalInerface` but from what you write I suspect that even you don't understand what you are doing. The [**call()**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call()) take only function name as first argument and rest as parameters to this function. Unless I'm a fool your `call("function() { console.log("+data+") }")` should not work in the first place so I wonder where you get this output printed. And we are talking about video streaming...

Comment: `The alphanumeric name of the function to call in the container. Using a non-alphanumeric function name causes a runtime error (error 2155).` - of course "}" is alphanumeric and you got everything working correctly...

Comment: @PawełAudionysos: Actually the `ExternalInterface.call("function() { console.log("+data+") }")` in AS3 will alert variable `data` to the screen. I use it to make sure that AS3 did receive the correct value passed from jQuery, it doesn't do anything with the streaming, it just let me know that AS3 got the `streamID`.

Comment: Since my comment might a little bit long, you can check here for what I mean https://codepen.io/adamboy_1802/pen/MpqyML

Comment: _"Since it's a 2 ways video chat"_... then you need to make video chat application. Where is the webcam code? How will your camera send video to another computer (so you need a middle server) etc. Try finding some [AS3 tutorials](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=CwdVVqvOHYSIOt7LgdAP#q=as3+video+chat+tutorial&*) on this topic. Asking how to pass variables between JS & AS3 or even using `POST` (_ie:_ post what server upload?) and using `.play("1234")` is going in the wrong direction (unless there is extra info that you did not tell us?). Read how video chat works then use `socket` of JS/AS3.